Can pthread_exit be used with noexcept functions?
I have a model where minimal work happens on main thread, and almost all work happens on worker threads. I want to ensure that the main thread NEVER dies and ALWAYS returns back to the OS.
Since, all my work is happening on worker threads, I want to kill the worker threads when some critical resource is not available. This allows me to efficiently write code without handling errors everywhere. For example, I require to allocate some memory on heap. I can invoke 'malloc' to do so, but 'malloc' may return nullptr, and instead of handling it every time I want to allocate memory, I simply want to kill the thread. Below is a sample code

void BlockMainThread () noexcept; // Wait on a semaphore
void ReleaseMainThread () noexcept; // Release the semaphore

int gExitStatus = 0;
bool gShouldRun = true;

[[noreturn]]
void
KillThread (int pExitStatus) noexcept
{
    gExitStatus = pExitStatus;

    ReleaseMainThread ();

    pthread_exit (nullptr); // Calls __forced_unwind internally
}

void *
Malloc (int pSize) noexcept
{
    void * ptr = malloc (pSize);

    if (!ptr)
        KillThread (1);

    return ptr;
}

void *
ThreadFunc (void *) noexcept // Executed by ALL worker threads
{
    printf ("Thread Started\n");

    while (gShouldRun) { // Do work till time to exit

        char * ptr = (char *) Malloc (100000);

        // Operate on ptr without needing to worry about ptr being NULL

        free (ptr);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int
main ()
{
        pthread_t tid1;
        pthread_t tid2; // And so on

    pthread_create (&tid1, nullptr, ThreadFunc, nullptr); // And so on

    BlockMainThread ();

    gShouldRun = false; // Stop the loop on which threads are spinning

    pthread_join (tid1, nullptr); // Join with all threads

    if (gExitStatus == 0) // All was good
        return 0;

    // Else log a message depending on the gExitStatus

    printf ("Something went wrong");

    return gExitStatus;
}

All the functions are marked as noexcept, which means that none of the functions should ever do a throw. Else std::terminate will be invoked, and not allowing the main thread to return (which as stated earlier, is something I do NOT want to happen).
However, pthread_exit des a throw of 'abi::__forced_unwind' exception. And this exception is something that needs to be rethrown if caught (hence no point in catching it). And due to this, std::terminate is invoked (since my functions are noexcept). This prevents the main thread from logging what has gone wrong.
If the functions are NOT marked with noexcept, the thread unwinds and main thread will continue as expected.
This happens only on Linux OS. The same code does NOT throw the exception when used on Apple and Android Kernel.
Questions:

Is there something I can do to prevent std::terminate when pthread_exit is called within a noexcept function?
Can I use noexcept at all if I want to use this model?
Are there any platform-specific workarounds for Linux to mimic the behavior on Apple and Android?

Context and Considerations:

Platform Differences: On Linux, pthread_exit uses __forced_unwind for stack unwinding and cleanup, which throws an exception. This is not the case on Apple and Android, where pthread_exit does not involve throwing exceptions.
Exception Handling: The __forced_unwind exception is special and must propagate through stack frames without being caught, as catching it and not rethrowing can lead to undefined behavior.
Resource Management: The goal is to terminate worker threads cleanly without complicating error handling in every allocation or critical section.


No you don't want to kill the other threads. You want them to co-operatively shut down. And don't use pthreads, use std::thread, std::mutex, std::condition_variable, std::scoped_lock/std::unique_lock. These have been available since C++11 and will really help you write cleaner code.

Killing threads is almost always wrong. When they die they do not clean up any resources/locks they've got and so you'll likely end up failing anyway unless you are very careful.

Does your code have to be C++?  Rust does not have exceptions.  It allows for a non-main thread to panic that will unwind its stack and shutdown the thread, but not terminate the program.  (A panic in the main thread will terminate the program.)

Although killing threads indeed is almost always the wrong thing to do, the OP has made a poor choice of words there.  What they actually describe, and what their code demonstrates, is a thread terminating (normally) by calling pthread_exit().

@JohnBollinger Yes I agree it is a poor choice for words. But still I see no need to use "C" style coding in the current age of C++.

I didn't claim that the OP's strategy was a good one, @PepijnKramer.  In fact, I'm inclined to think that the most appropriate answer would be one that explains why they shouldn't try to do what they are doing.

You wrote:

'malloc' may return nullptr, and instead of handling it every time I want to allocate memory, I simply want to kill the thread.

... by which you apparently mean that you want the thread to terminate its own execution immediately, without returning from the initial call to its entry-point function or any others in the current call chain.  However, to "kill" a thread will be understood by many as some other thread performing an action that forces the thread in question to terminate abruptly.
Nevertheless, many of the same issues afflicting that scenario also afflict your plan to stop thread execution by calling pthread_exit().  Large among them, since you're already thinking along those lines, is whether or how the stack gets properly unwound if you bypass normal function return via pthread_exit().  Presumably you do want a clean unwind, with all appropriate destructor calls, etc..  The normal mechanism for that is to throw an exception.
By marking your functions noexcept, you are making a claim that is semantically false even if, on some platforms, it happens to be technically true.  Compare the behavior of std::longjmp, which is a reasonably close analogy to what you seem to want.  C++ places these restrictions, as described by cppreference:

On top of C longjmp, C++ std::longjmp has more restricted behavior.
If replacing std::longjmp with throw and setjmp with catch would invoke a non-trivial destructor for any automatic object, the behavior of such std::longjmp is undefined.

You're looking at considerations similar to those that inspire the std::longjmp restrictions, even though C++ does not speak directly to them (and why should it?).
You remark:

This happens only on Linux OS. The same code does NOT throw the
exception when used on Apple and Android Kernel.

Glibc's pthreads implementation is providing for the correct stack unwinding.  Possibly MacOS's and Androids' have different mechanisms for that, but possibly they just leave you hanging.
The best thing to do is to work with C++ instead of against it.  That means:

In C++, use std::thread and associated mechanisms instead of pthreads.
Threading mechanisms notwithstanding, if you must transfer control up the call chain without returning, then do it by throwing an exception.  That is C++'s standard mechanism for such control transfers.  If you happen to be inclined to avoid using exceptions, then you should not be any more satisfied with alternative means to achieve analogous behavior.
noexcept should be understood broadly, not narrowly: a function so declared is expected always to terminate execution by returning to its caller, so much so that it is a serious internal error for it not to do so.

As to your specific questions:


Is there something I can do to prevent std::terminate when pthread_exit is called within a noexcept function?


Yes -- use a pthreads library that doesn't do that.  You've already found two such libraries.
Perhaps there are more practical approaches on platforms where you don't get that for free, but that's ultimately the wrong question.


Can I use noexcept at all if I want to use this model?


You shouldn't.  In fact, if you want to stick with the model you are using then you should adjust it to explicitly throw exceptions instead of calling pthread_exit() to terminate threads from down the call chain.  noexcept is obviously incorrect once you switch to that, more C++ly correct, variation.


Are there any platform-specific workarounds for Linux to mimic the behavior on Apple and Android?


I hesitate to say "no", because it's too likely that one of the many knowledgeable and clever people around here will come up with something that fits your description.  But if one did, should you use it?  Without even evaluating the tradeoffs involved, I am comfortable opining that no, you should not.
